# convert unique chars from string to Table Char Int

Tags: string, haskell, char

Im trying to convert a string to it's unique chars along with an integer counter to the following interface:

```
empty :: Table k v
insert :: Eq k => Table k v -> k -> v -> Table k v
exists :: Eq k => Table k v -> k -> Bool
lookup :: Eq k => Table k v -> k -> Maybe v
delete :: Eq k => Table k v -> k -> Table k v
iterate :: Table k v -> (b -> (k, v) -> b) -> b -> b
keys :: Table k v -> (b -> k -> b) -> b -> b
values :: Table k v -> (b -> v -> b) -> b -> b
```

My function so far is as follows:

```
auxCharacterCounts :: String -> Table Char Int
auxCharacterCounts (x:xs)
| length (x:xs) > 1 = (Table.insert Table.empty x (length $ filter (\y -> y == x) (x:xs)))
```

For example passing the string "sassa" to `auxCharacterCounts` and then running a `lookup tablename 's'` would yield `Just 3`

Giving us the indication that we have 3 occurences of the char 's' in the string "sassa". What im stuck at is wrapping my head on how to get the other characters, so to speak running `lookup tablename 'a'` would yield the result `Just 2` (against the string "sassa")

Im not sure how to run this recursivly, can I pass the tail somehow? But if I did it will find the char 's' several times more and might result in unnessecary resource usage?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Write an auxiliary function

```
increment :: (Eq k, Num v) => Table k v -> k -> Table k v
```

to add one to a value in the table. You can implement it using the table functions you have.

Then scan the string, and increment the table once for every character.